# How do I call the SharePoint Search API for Recent News within a SharePoint Framework webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx, sharepoint-search

I am creating a webpart using the SharePoint Framework and I am trying to use the search API to get some recent news articles to create a news carousel.

Here is my code snippet:

```
  private async _getNewsFeedSearchResults() : Promise<string> {
    let request_url = `https://[mytenant].sharepoint.com/sites/test-site/_api/search/query?querytext='(IsDocument:True)+AND+(FileExtension:aspx)+AND+(PromotedState:2)'`;
    const response = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(request_url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1);
    return await response.text();
  }
```

The response I get from SharePoint is:

> {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError","message":"Unknown Error"}}

I suspect that the problem is in my `QueryText`:

> /_api/search/query?querytext='(IsDocument:True)+AND+(FileExtension:aspx)+AND+(PromotedState:2)'

I also tried

> /_api/search/query?QueryText=%27((IsDocument%3ATrue)%20AND%20(FileExtension%3Aaspx)%20AND%20(PromotedState%3A2))%27

and I continue to get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QueryText is fine. You need to specify the OData version headers to v3 as the search API doesn't support v4.

```
const response = await this.context.spHttpClient.get(
  request_url,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
  {
    headers: {
      "odata-version": "3.0",
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Hey @MichaelHan_MSFT This got me further along but now it says I am unauthorized. Any tips? { \"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.\"}}}

Comment: Looks like you donot have permission to the site.

Comment: I think I own the site.  But I am logged into the site, I have published my custom app (SharePoint Framework), I am using `this.context.spHttpClient` -- could it be because of the fully-qualified URL?  should I pass relative paths?   If I grab the request URL and drop it into the browser address bar, then I see the results I expect.

Comment: it seems like there is strict CORS configuration on the search api.  I have two site. dev & staging.  I was testing in dev with the relative url from when I switch the code so that the url of the search query match the site where the app was installed -- then everything work as expected. -- related, I am able to call _api/web/lists cross-site but not search.